# Collapse expand animation without transitioning the `height` property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I read tons of articles that say you should stick with `transform` and `opacity` if you want smooth CSS transitions.

For example: https://www.netcentric.biz/insights/2017/09/css-transition-performance.html

**The core idea always seems to be:**

> *... to optimise your transition experience, the browser should ensure that the animated CSS doesn’t cause a repaint.*

**QUESTION**

I need to do something like the snippet below: expand / collapse filters boxes when user clicks on it. So far, I can only do it by transitioning the `height` property of them. Can I do it any other way without needing to transition the `height` property like I did?

---

**Note:** This is a mobile view and I do want `Filters` to "push" the `Results` down when it opens. Results will be a gallery with 30 products with thumbnails, titles and links.

```js
const styled = window.styled;

const Header_DIV = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
`;

const Main_DIV = styled.div`
  padding-top: 42px;
`;

const Filters1_DIV = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: ${props => props.open ? '100px' : '16px' };
  transition: height ease-out .5s;
`;

const Filters2_DIV = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: ${props => props.open ? '100px' : '16px' };
  transition: height ease-out .5s;
`;

const Results_DIV = styled.div`
  background-color: lightgray;
`;

function App() {
  
  const [openFilter1,setOpenFilter1] = React.useState(false);
  const [openFilter2,setOpenFilter2] = React.useState(false);
  
  function toggleFilter1() {
    setOpenFilter1((prevState) => !prevState);  
  }
  
  function toggleFilter2() {
    setOpenFilter2((prevState) => !prevState);  
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header_DIV>
        Header
      </Header_DIV>
      <Main_DIV>
        <Filters1_DIV
          onClick={toggleFilter1}
          open={openFilter1}
        >
          Filter1 ----------- Click to open/close!
        </Filters1_DIV>
        <Filters2_DIV
          onClick={toggleFilter2}
          open={openFilter2}
        >
          Filter2 ----------- Click to open/close!
        </Filters2_DIV>
        <Results_DIV>
          Results
        </Results_DIV>
      </Main_DIV>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: You could transition the 'max-height` instead. This would still trigger a redraw though but it would allow you to resect the natural heights of the elements. If you want "the filters to 'push' the results down" I doubt it is possible to reflow the content _without_ the browser having to redraw.

Comment: See also: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: @Moob using `max-height` would trigger a redraw but in a more efficient way, is that it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use `transform: scale(0)` with `opacity: 0` in transition. But you may need to tweak your layout and styles a little bit.